# What is Storm King's Thunder's "Appendix E"?

Tags: dnd-5e, errata, storm-kings-thunder

On page 184 of Storm King's Thunder, there is a reference to an Appendix E:

> "Inscribed on the floor of the forge is the ild (fire) rune (see appendix E)."

But there doesn't appear to be an appendix E that I can find. Is there more information about what exists there? What is this trying to direct me to?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per a [tweet by Christopher Perkins](https://twitter.com/ChrisPerkinsDnD/status/830568815033409537),

> The text should direct you to page 7, not appendix E.

That is to say,

> It's just telling you to refer to the picture of what the runes look like at the beginning of the Introduction, so you know how to draw them. There isn't any further magical ability or the like involved.

It appears to just be an error in editing.